# Get Cookies in java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-filters

I Have Problem when I create cookies and store to another page using servlet.
I have no create JSESSIONID, I Just Create name,
but Why JSESSIONID always create automatic when I refresh the page
Please Help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYoBD.png)

```
    public class ControllerHelper extends HelperBase {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ControllerHelper(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        super(request, response);
    }


public void doGet(String address) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("helper", this);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Cookie[] ck=request.getCookies();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    if(ck!=null) {

        String name=ck[1].getValue();
          if(!name.equals("")||name!=null){  
              out.print("<b>Welcome to Profile</b>");  
              out.print("<br>Welcome, "+name);  
          }  

        request.setAttribute("stts_log", "Login");
        request.setAttribute("sess", name);
        request.setAttribute("btn_modal", "exambutton");
        request.setAttribute("btn_href", "#");

    }else {
        request.setAttribute("sess", "");
        request.setAttribute("stts_log", "Logout");
        request.setAttribute("btn_modal", "");
        request.setAttribute("btn_href", "logout");
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/header.jsp").include(request, response);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/"+address).include(request, response);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/footer.jsp").include(request,response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why JSESSIONID always create automatic when I refresh the page

Because of `request.getSession().setAttribute("helper", this);` that creates your sessionid (the JSESSIONID is a session tracking cookie).

Comment: Oke Elliot, I get it,
And I Have Question Again,
Why is like this String 
name=ck[1].getValue();
Whereas in Tutuorial the Value is name=ck[0].getValue();
I get tutorial from this https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-login-and-logout-example-using-cookies

Comment: It's an array of cookies; the index of the cookie in the array is arbitrary (it's almost certainly the order the browser sends them).

Comment: Oke...
Thanks For Ur Help,,.
I'm New to java, before I just Php and so many different methode..
btw I need your advice, Which one the best, Session or Cookies for security login ?
and can you give me some link for I learn about auth in java servlet ?

Comment: [JAAS Authentication Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html)